# Background image not stretching when rotating

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have set the background for a given view using the following code, however, when I rotate the device, it just repeats the image. what I want is for it to stretch to the rotated width and height.. I know how to do it in Interface Builder but this view does not have a nib.

```
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mainbg.png"]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically set the `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`, e.g.

```
[imageView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
```